# printing json values inside array using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to print the football value which is inside array using JS. I am not sure how to print it in JS. Right now when I try it prints as `undefined`. I am providing part of my JS and JSON below, can you guys tell me how to fix it?

```
if (item.data.football == true) {
    console.log("print football---->" + item.data[0].football);
}
```

```js
"data": [{
    "sportsProperty": "Insurance",
    "football": true
},
{
    "sportsProperty": "Insurance",
    "football": true
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property of your object is an array, so you need to access its members by index. Try this:

```
if (item.data[0].football) { // note the [0] after 'data'
    // do something...
    console.log(item.data[0]);
}
```

The above will only access the first item in the array. If you want to work with all of them you need to use a loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < item.data.length; i++) {
    if (item.data[i].football) {
        // do something...
        console.log(item.data[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/s21darya/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring `item`? By writing `item.data`, you're implying that the `data` object lies within an `item` object. In order to work, your code should look something like the following:

```
var item = {
  "data": [
    {
      "sportsProperty": "Insurance",
      "football": true
    },
    {
      "sportsProperty": "Insurance",
      "football": true
    }
  ]
};
```

Also, `item.data.football` returns `undefined`, because you need to specify a location within the array. Otherwise, you can ask:

```
if (!!item.data)
```

Which will return `true` if `item.data` is not an empty object.

Let me know if you need any further help.